# Copy file to newly created directories

Tags: c#, file-copying, create-directory

So I have a bit complicated one, I'm trying to create a "template creator". User will input data via comboboxes and textboxes into a form, from which a button generates the names (combination of inputs). After that next button creates directories as required. Until this point everything is ok, however, after this, I prompted a question whether the user wants to start copying files to the newly created directories.

Current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace ME_Nitra_BIW_App
{
    public partial class ToolingDesign : Form
    {

        // create folder path to enable new folder creation
        private void btnGenerateFilePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            tBoxFilePath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            btnCreateDir.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnCreateDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tBoxFilePath.Text))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No file path selected!");
            }
            else
            {

                // for Assembly folder
                string fileNameAssy = "FIXED_PARTS_PRODUCT.CATProduct";
                string sourcePathAssy = @"c:\Users\mjanus\Downloads\CATIAV5\START_MODELS\CAT_PRODUCTS";
                string targetPathAssy = tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text + "_U000" + "_ASSEMBLY";
                

                // use path class to manipulate file and directory paths
                string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePathAssy, fileNameAssy);
                string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPathAssy, fileNameAssy);
                string dirPath = tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text;

                // create new folders with generated names
                btnGenerateFilePath.Enabled = false;
                btnCreateDir.Enabled = false;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U000" + "_ASSEMBLY");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U001" + "_PRODUCT_PARTS");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U002" + "_CLAMP_STUDY");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U003" + "_GUN_STUDY");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U004" + "_PRODUCT_PARTS");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U005" + "_MECHANICAL_SEQUENCES");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U006" + "_MISCELLANEOUS");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U007" + "_SUPPORT");

                // ask if user wants to copy template files to the newly created folders
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Directories successfuly created!" + Environment.NewLine + "Do you wish to copy files now?", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    // if the directory folder already exists, this method does not create a new directory
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPathAssy);
                    // overwrite the destination file if it already exists
                    System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
                    // start of copy
                    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePathAssy))
                    {
                        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePathAssy);

                        foreach (string s in files)
                        {
                            fileNameAssy = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                            destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPathAssy, fileNameAssy);
                            System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Source path does not exist!");
                    }
                }
                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

As you can see I've set the `targetPathAssy` to the same location as what the new folder is created, but I'm not sure if the code can read that? Or how could I store that newly created directory path and call it?

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` to build paths, not string concatenation.. And please, in the interests of creating code that is actually readable, **rename your controls** after you drop them on a form. Code that is full of Textbox6, Button23, Label19 is effectively obfuscated garbage.. You have the luxury of being able to nip back into the designer and check whether it's textBox34 or textBox38 that is the first name, but we don't.. And just think, you wouldn't even have to nip back into the designer if it was called firstNameTextBox

Comment: _" I'm not sure if the code can read that?"_ Did you test it? Did you check the value of the variable with the debugger? What's the actual problem? Or is this just a gut feeling?

Comment: I have issues understanding your question. You set the variable `targetPathAssy` to a certain value. The same value you use to create a directory a few lines beneath. And later, you try to create the same directory again, this time using the variable `targetPathAssy`. I'm not sure if that is the issue you're referring to in your question but the code doesn't seem to make sense at this point.

Comment: I thought that I could re-use the same directory path, that's why asked whether that can work or not, basically after creating the new directories I want to copy certain files to those new directories

I get the 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occured in mscorlib.dll, Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\mjanus\Desktop\Test\L462_BR02_010_011_COM_TR\L462_BR02_010_011_COM_TR_U000_ASSEMBLY\FIXED_PARTS_PRODUCT.CATProduct' is denied.

Comment: ok, turned out that some files were in read-only, and the code actually works, I was just too hasty, however, instead of just copying the file I stated in ```fileNameAssy``` it copies all files from the directory, I'll try to modify the code somehow

Comment: Let's say you create a base path to simplify things and make it better readable: `var templatePath = tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text + @"\" ;`. Then use `templatePath` instead of `tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text` in your  code. Also, I noticed you're using it too many times, e.g. `tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text + "_U000" + "_ASSEMBLY"` : Shouldn't it be  like `templatePath + fileNameAssy` if you declared `var fileNameAssy =  ...` previously ? Makes the code better understandable and less error-prone.

Comment: makes sense, after I finish everything I will definitely tidy it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and it's much simpler than what I've tried before.

Here's the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace ME_Nitra_BIW_App
{
    public partial class ToolingDesign : Form
    {
        public ToolingDesign()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
            radioButton2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);   
        }
private void btnCreateDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tBoxFilePath.Text))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No file path selected!");
            }
            else
            {
                // directory path
                string dirPath = tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text;   
                
                // where to paste the files
                string targetPathAssy = dirPath + "_U000" + "_ASSEMBLY";

                // create new folders with generated names
                btnGenerateFilePath.Enabled = false;
                btnCreateDir.Enabled = false;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tBoxFilePath.Text + @"\" + tBoxFolderName.Text);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U000" + "_ASSEMBLY");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U001" + "_PRODUCT_PARTS");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U002" + "_CLAMP_STUDY");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U003" + "_GUN_STUDY");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U004" + "_PRODUCT_PARTS");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U005" + "_MECHANICAL_SEQUENCES");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U006" + "_MISCELLANEOUS");
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath + "_U007" + "_SUPPORT");

                // ask if user wants to copy template files to the newly created folders
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Directories successfuly created!" + Environment.NewLine + "Do you wish to copy files now?", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    // test copy

                    File.Copy(@"Resources\UNIT_START_PRODUCT.CATProduct", targetPathAssy + @"\" + "UNIT_START_PRODUCT.CATProduct");
                    
                }
                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        // create folder path to enable new folder creation
        private void btnGenerateFilePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            tBoxFilePath.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
            btnCreateDir.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
}
```

The change:

Turns out that I can use the same string to copy the file to the newly created directory which uses the string `dirPath` as shown above. Although I've embedded the files into the application (ease of use, not sure if I would get a dedicated folder on the server) I've used the

```
File.Copy(@"Resources\UNIT_START_PRODUCT.CATProduct", targetPathAssy + @"\" + "UNIT_START_PRODUCT.CATProduct");
```

I had to add the `@"\"` because otherwise the copied file would have the `targetPathAssy` added to its name instead of going into the specific folder.

Hope this helps someone in the future